# How do you paste what is in your highlight clipboard?

Tags: key-bindings, os-clipboard

I want to map `vv` to paste my highlighted text clipboard as opposed to vim's clipboard or the copy clipboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Note: This only applies in unix with X11 environments.

The "highlighted text" clipboard is known as the PRIMARY X selection (vs SECONDARY or CLIPBOARD X selections). Vim, when built with X support, provides access to the PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD selections via the registers `*`, `+`

(you can find more information in `:help quoteplus` and `:help quotestar`)

So, to map pasting highlighted text, you might do something like this:

```
:nnoremap vv "*p
```

though, that mapping only saves one keystroke at the expense of toggling visual mode. You could just type `"*p` or `"*P`